# アプリのサブスクで「IMMEDIATE_WITH_TIME_PRORATION」を設定の場合のアップグレード時の充当処理に関して

Tags: google-play

ライトプラン（月額）とプレミアムプラン（月額、年額）のサブスクアプリを運用しています。

ユーザーがライトプランからプレミアムプランにアップグレードした際の充当処理に関して質問です。

「IMMEDIATE_WITH_TIME_PRORATION」を設定している場合、アップグレード時にアップグレード前のプランの残日数がある際には、残日数分の残額がプレミアムプランに充当されると思います。

例えば下記の場合、端数が生じると思うのですがその場合の端数の処理がどうなるのか知りたいです。

※金額は分かりやすくするために仮置きです。

・ライトプラン：月額250円
・プレミアムプラン：月額600円

ライトプランを15日分使用したタイミングでアップグレード。残額125円が存在。

プレミアムプランを日割りにした場合 600円÷30日=20円 なので、毎日20円づつ充当される。

6日分充当されたタイミングで残り5円となり、1日の日割り額に満たない状態になる。この場合にこの5円の処理はどうなるのでしょうか。

ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、教えていただけますと大変助かります。

宜しくお願いいたします。